# How to link the thumbnail image to it's parent blog in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, hyperlink, blogs

I'm displaying latest 10 images uploaded by the displayed users in their respective profile page (buddypress.. I'm using this code to pull the images:

$media = get_posts(array(

'author' => bp_displayed_user_id(),

'post_type' => 'attachment',

'numberposts' => 10,

'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg'
));

foreach ($media as $image) {

list($src) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'thumbnail');

echo 'img src="'.$src.'" >';}

They work fine but here I'm unable to link the images to respective blog post.. They are simply showing the images without link attached to it.. I want to link all those images to it's parents blog post..

Thanks.. Your volunteered help will be highly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

try the code below.

```
$media = get_posts(array(

    'author' => bp_displayed_user_id(),

    'post_type' => 'attachment',

    'numberposts' => 10,

    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg' ));

    foreach ($media as $image) {

    list($src) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'thumbnail');
   #To add full image in the link

    list($fullImage) = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'full');

    $parent = get_post_ancestors( $image->ID ); #Fetching the parent of the attachment

    $permalink = get_permalink($parent[0]); #Getting the permalink of the parent.


    echo '<a href="'.$fullImage.'"><img src="'.$src.'" ></a>';}
```

***[Source](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/144614/get-post-id-by-attachment-id), [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_ancestors)***

***Enjoy. Happy Coding.***

Comment: Thanks for the response #Ashok.. But as I see the above code just refreshes the page.. I doesn't link the post.. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey Bro, See the variables $parent, $permalink I've used and I've added the link tag which you've missed in your code.

Comment: I just rechecked the code and this variable  $permalink = get_permalink($parent[0]); doesn't actually links to the parent post.. They simply are link to the displayed page (i.e, refreshes the page).. can you check back the code..? Thanks for the follow up response

Comment: Jay find the demo below. http://ashokg.in/wp-test/attachments/ (Authentication : @Utube!23)

Comment: Hi Ashok, I couldn't get it working.. I presume it could be the problem of using in the buddypress template.. The other problem could be my theme.. I can't really get to troubleshoot on this or rewrite codes..

Comment: Can this code be rewrite to get link to "media file" instead of parent post or attachment page? This will help me to open images in lightbox.. Appreciate your follow up responses..